# How to get visitors/day from data.stackexchange?

Tags: support, api

I had written [a Python script](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30139/review-python-script-for-getting-the-stats-of-codereview-se-into-a-file-for-anal) for getting the stats of codereview.SE from the front page of codereview.SE into a text file. A review of the script has suggested that I should instead use data.stackexchange to get the data specifically from [this page](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info#filter=default&site=codereview&run=true). It does not have visitors/day on this page. I wanted to find the growth of the the website so that is needed.

How can I get visitors/day from the API for codereview.SE?

Comment: You should use the API, not the Data Explorer. Start [here](http://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register).

Comment: Adding to @ShaWizDowArd's comment: the data explorer isn't up to date. It's essentially a "backup" of the actual database made every 3(?) months.

Comment: @Cole a while ago they changed it so the data is updated once a week, see [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/help): "The data is updated early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC". Not live, but not that old either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visitors per day is not available via the API nor from the data explorer.

This can be gotten through [quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I can get that from the front page of codereview also. But as the website is showing that on its front page I thought that it would be available via the API also.